# Matrix Table with Hashmap printing

Tags: java, matrix, hashmap, duplicates

I making a code as an assignment through Hadoop to write a Matrix table of the value's read from a text file. Basically it has to read how many times a character comes after a certain other character.

I have those value's already though my code in hadoop and put them into a hashmap <char1,hashmap<char2,value>>  And pass them on to a function called Frequency table:

```
 public void FrequencieTable(HashMap<Character, HashMap<Character,Integer>> charFrequentie){
    String theRowList = "";
    String theColumnList = "";
    for(Character row : charFrequentie.keySet()){
        theRowList += "\n" + row;
        for(Character column : charFrequentie.get(row).keySet()) {
            theColumnList += column.charValue() + "\t";
            theRowList += "\t" +  charFrequentie.get(row).get(column);
        }
        
        System.out.println("\t" + theColomList +  "\n");
        System.out.println(theRowList);
    }
}
```

Only this gives the wrong output because it should only display every single char like "H" once on a row and a column and if there is not any data there it should display 0.

Basically it gives this output:

```
    u   s   a   o   e   m   g   d   t   n   j   t   a   n   g   t   e   m   a   t   e   e   a   o   e   u   s   g   l   j   k   


g   1   1   2   2
d   1   1
e   1   2   2   1   1
a   2   2   3
n   2   2
o   2   1
```

While it should be something like this: ( No duplications )

```
    u   s   a   o   e   m   g   d   t   n   j   
g   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   2   2
d   1   1   0   0   1   0   3   0   0   0   0
```

Does anybody have any idea what we should do? We are totally clueless atm.

Thank you already

Comment: `Dead Stackoverflow` - RIP ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what exactly your data should represent but the basic problem seems to be your inner loop:

```
for(Character column: charFrequentie.get(row).keySet()){
    theColumnList += column.charValue() + "\t";
    theRowList += "\t" +  charFrequentie.get(row).get(column);
}
```

Here you would add the *same* character to the column list if it exists in the mapping for multiple rows, e.g. if you have a frequency for a->c and b->c you'd have c twice in your column list.

Besides that you'd need to iterate over *all* characters in your mappings and in the same order. You currently just use the values per row and since you don't know which column they're in you can't fill the other columns with 0s.

To fix that you'd have to loop twice (otherwise you could miss trailing zeros in the top rows):

- once to get all columns
- once to actually print the rows

The order of columns would either have to be supplied/defined or depend on the order in the mappings.

Example:

```
//Step 1: collect all the columns that have values
Set<Character> columns = new LinkedHashSet<>();
for(Character row : charFrequentie.keySet()){
  //gets the mapped characters for the row and adds them in the order they are returned ignoring any duplicates 
  columns.addAll(charFrequentie.get(row).keySet());
}

//Step 2: print
for( Character col : columns ) {
  //print the columns as the first line
}

//here you iterate over the rows since you'll print line by line
for(Character row : charFrequentie.keySet()){
  //go over the columns in the same order for each row
  for( Character col : columns ) {
    //get the frequency for the column in that row, which might be null       
    Integer frequency = charFrequentie.get(row).get(col);

    //if there is no value for the column in the current row just print 0
    if( frequency == null ) {
      //print 0
    } else {
      //there is a frequency value so just print it         
    }
  }
}
```

Two notes on the columns and their ordering:

- Since you only provide hashmaps you can't determine the order of the columns (with `LinkedHashSet` the order would be as returned by the maps but that would still not be defined since hash maps normally don't define an order. If you want a specific order you'd have to sort the columns (use a sorted set then) or provide them manually.
- If you don't have entries for frequency 0 you'll not get any column that has all zeros as in your example where `o` and `m` have only 0-values. In that case you'd have to provide them manually to get columns that have no frequency data.

**Edit:**

To make the example clearer assume the following input data (format: row,column,frequency)

```
a,a,1
a,b,5
a,c,3
b,a,5
b,e,7
```

This will result in a column set having the values `a`, `b`, `c`, `e` in any order (since you use hashmaps).

The output could look like this (again the order can be different due to using hashmaps, I just use a random order):

```
  b e a c
b 0 7 5 0  
a 5 0 1 3
```

Comment: Mm this makes more sence but the problem that double A's might be printed or any character actually. Basicly the row should only display the character once 

So if "a,n,4" (bassicly meaning if an happens 4 times and "a,p,5" happens 5 times it should siplay a only once and not twice.

So this should be the result:
          A
     N   4
     P   5 

And not 

         A   A
    N   4
    P        5

Comment: @Tvt you realize that column values are printed only once for each row and that using a set for `columns` effectively removes any duplicates? Of course if you have data like "a,n,4" and "n,a,4" you'd get 4 entries: 2 lines with values "a, 0, 4" and "n, 4, 0". - that said, I'm not sure where you get that `A A N 4 P 5` from.

Comment: yea i do but is there a way to filter this? To make it look like this: http://prnt.sc/accgqi

Don't know if this is even possible.

Comment: @Tvt of course this is possible. What do you mean with "filter this"? If you mean to filter the columns just provide them manually (i.e. select which columns you want to see and don't collect them from the mappings). If the rows should be filtered as well just check whether the key is in the allowed set of keys (could be `columns` as per your example) and if not you skip that row.

Comment: What i mean with "Filter this" is that i would like to check if the collom like A already exists and if yes apply it to that col/row so it would be in order.

I do not know how it should check it's position again then so it posts in the right row+kolom

Comment: @Tvt that's what I do in my example: iterate over the rows, for each row iterate over the columns (always in the same order for that call) and check whether it exists in that row. If not you print 0 at that position otherwise you print the actual value.

Comment: Thnx alot btw Thomas!  Will try this later tonight or tommorow morning. Will let you know if it works! And then mark awnser ofcourse